# Microservice Event driven communication - how to notify the caller only on command / event approach

Tags: microservices, kafka-consumer-api, distributed-system, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I wonder, how do you avoid notifying all services that consume the same event? For example, service A and service B both of them consume event X. Based on some rules you want to send the event X only for service A. I am not talking about consumer groups (kafka) or even correlation-Id. As I am using Event-Driven microservices with the approach of command & event.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's quite easy by using **Kafka partitions/partition-key.**
For example: In your topic **X**, you could just create it with many partitions. For each invocation, every service must specify its key, so based on the key, Kafka will do the rest of the job. So every time *Service A sends a command*, the *consumer Service (the one who handles the command)* will send the event with the **same key**. So in the end, **Service A** (the producer of the command) will receive the event on its own partition and will be the only service receiving it. So based on the Command/Event approach it may work.

On the other hand, by doing so, you are limiting one of the main benefits of partition which is allowing the scalability.